# Why is $\bigwedge^2( \mathbb{Z}[x,y])=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

According to a comment in Dummit and Foote, $\bigwedge^2( \mathbb{Z}[x,y])=0$.  Why is this true?

I can't convince myself that monomials such that $x \otimes y$ or $x \otimes 1$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ would go to zero once we quotient out by the ideal generated by $p(x,y) \otimes p(x,y)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Lambda^2$?  If you mean the wedge square as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then this isn't true...

Comment: I mean the wedge squared.

Comment: This still isn't true...but it's also not true that the wedge square is the quotient by the ideal generated by $p(x,y)\otimes p(x,y)$--the wedge square is only a module, not a ring.  Can you clarify exactly what your definition is?

Comment: I am using the definition that $\wedge^2(\mathbb{Z}[x,y])=T^2(\mathbb{Z}[x,y])/ A^2(\mathbb{Z}[x,y])$ where I thought $T^2= \mathbb{Z}[x,y] \otimes \mathbb{Z}[x,y])$

Comment: What do you mean by $A^2$?  And why do you think that the wedge square should be $0$?

Comment: By $A^2$ i mean the ideal generated by monomials of the form $m \otimes m$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. I am reading a comment of this in Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only true if you are taking the wedge square of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$-module, not as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  The wedge square is then defined as the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ by the $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$-submodule $K$ generated by elements of the form $p(x,y)\otimes p(x,y)$.  Taking $p(x,y)=1$, $1\otimes 1$ is an element of the submodule $K$.  But $1\otimes 1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$-module, since any simple tensor $p(x,y)\otimes q(x,y)$ is equal to the scalar product $(p(x,y)q(x,y))\cdot (1\otimes 1)$.  (Indeed, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\cong\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ by sending $p(x,y)\otimes q(x,y)$ to $p(x,y)q(x,y)$, and $1\otimes 1$ maps to $1\in\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ under this isomorphism.)

(Note there is nothing special about $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$: this argument shows that for any commutative ring $R$, $\bigwedge_R^2(R)=0$.)